# Tizen Native Service is not getting Sensor Privileges

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator

I'm working on a Tizen Hybrid App (Web UI + Native Service) for Gear S3 Frontier watch. I'm getting the sensor privileges in the Web UI and the launched Native Service *somehow* gets the same privileges. But since I've reset my watch, I'm not getting the privileges in the service application, so the **Tizen service is unable to access the sensors.**

**My Web UI Code:**

```
function init() {

    //Get Privileges
    getPrivileges();

    //Laucnh Service Application
    startService();
}
```

The Web UI asks for the privileges and launches the Service Application but **when I check for the privileges in service app, the result is `PRIVACY_PRIVILEGE_MANAGER_CHECK_RESULT_ASK`**.

I'm wondering why the same code works *fine* for the `Emulator`..

Answer (score 1):

Did you implement your code according to the guide page?

web app: https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/security/privacy-related-permissions

native app: https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/security/privacy-related-permissions

If an app receives RESULT_ASK, it should call ppm_request_permission API to get user's consent.

This feature was enable since Tizen 4.0, so this behavior can be different as per the Tizen version of device/emulator.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the code from the guide page. The log file show that the status is `ASK` in the Service. I'm not expecting the Service App to ask for the Privilege because `Service` is without UI.. but I'm wondering why the Emulator (that is also the same version 4.0 as the device) has no problem with this code, the Service gets the Privileges _automatically_

Comment: Getting privacy privileges automatically is not allowed by legal issues.

Comment: You can find the privacy privileges in this page: https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/training/web-application/understanding-tizen-programming/security-and-api-privileges

Comment: @LunchBasketball , Many thanks for the response. I'm using the privilege checker and getting no issue in my Web UI code, the issue here is that when the Web UI launches the Native Service after getting the privileges, I want those privileges in the Native Service as well. Since that is a project without UI, I can't get Sensor Privileges in the Native Service.